# Data Type Mismatch In Criteria Expression error in join query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm attempting to join the query table `qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling` to the basic table `timezonesCombined` to the make a single field `TZfactor` from the table available for a larger query. This seems so simple but I'm getting

> data type mismatch in criteria expression

when I run the query.

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.EbiquityId,
       qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.AdTitle,
       qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.Brand,
       qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.Product,
       qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.TransmissionDate,
       qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.tTime,
       qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.Region,
       qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.nMedium,
       qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.[Scaling Factor],
       qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.ZoneLookup,
       timezonesCombined.TZFactor
FROM qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling
  INNER JOIN timezonesCombined
    ON qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.ZoneLookup = timezonesCombined.[Zone#];
```

Hope someone can help, thanks in advance

Comment: Ever considered using table aliases? (E.g. `INNER JOIN timezonesCombined AS tc ON q.ZoneLookup = tc.[Zone#]`.)

Comment: What are data types of columns `qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling.ZoneLookup` and `timezonesCombined.[Zone#]`? Looks like they are different, so Access cannot compare them properly.

Comment: thanks @jarlh, I'm very new at Acces and SQL, but have started using alias in queries that exceed the build expression out of necessity, don't see how it would help in this scenario though?

Comment: @SergeyS. Both are numbers with no null values, TZfactor is to 4 decimals, Zonelookup is result of checking times in tTime are between Start and End for each [Zone#] and returning the number of the zone (integer from 1 to 11). 

Oddly, this query is not throwing the same error when I open it at home just now (Windows 10, Office 2016)(Work is WIndows7, Offfice 2013). However it is picking up the wrong values from [TZfactor]. I'll investigate further, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Played around trying to get correct values from [TZfactor] and now it's throwing the Data type Mismatch error again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by going back a step to qryJoinValidTXwithStationScaling and using criteria on tTime for each Timezone (Between starttime  And endtime ), then added correlating criteria for Zone# (1 thru 11) which returns correct TZfactor.